# Kite depth in sprite kit game

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I want to create a game kite flying  . Now suppose we have two button's Up and down. When we press on button  up kite go away from screen and it should look realistic small while  its going away and away on continues press . If we press on down it should come down in same way and it look bigger .

How can show kite depth on screen with sprite kit or any other framework ?

Thanks 
Rajender

Comment: Can you state your question more clearly? What have you tried?

Comment: Updated , just think how real kite flying works .

Answer (score 1):

You could try adjusting the `Scale` property of the `SKNode` when a user presses the up button. You'll have to detect the specific key type that you're looking for, but you could do something like:

```
- (void)handlePressDown:(UIGestureRecognizer)recognizer
{
    // ....Detect specific keystroke
    _kiteScaleAmount++;
    [kite setScale:_kiteScaleAmount];
}
```

More info on `SKNode` [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/SKNode).

Comment: Hi , Thanks for your reply , Is this will make kite realistic going away from screen ?

Comment: Realism is in the eye of the beholder.

Comment: @rickster is above solution will work ?

Comment: Looks like this solution is functional, yes. But whether this solution (or the one in my answer, for that matter) appears "realistic" to you is subjective (and also might have more to do with art assets than code).

Answer (score 0):

Since you included the [scenekit] tag in your question, perhaps you're also looking for 3D solutions?

You can use `SK3DNode` to add 3D content—an embedded SceneKit scene—to your otherwise 2D SpriteKit game. So, if you have a 3D model of a kite, you can build a SceneKit scene around that, then attach it to an `SK3DNode` in your game. Then, to make the kite get farther and nearer to the viewer, adjust the camera in the SceneKit scene.

Comment: Thanks for reply . I am not using any 3d object . Just want to know which framework i need to use for kite game for realistic view.